# React Routing, refresh does not render specific view, but redirects to parent view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

This is our parent view: 
http://localhost:8080/#/dashboard/

When I click on a link to Menu Navigation:
http://localhost:8080/#/dashboard/menu-navigation

This will load up the correct `menu-navigation` view, however if I refresh the app goes back to `/dashboard` instead of staying on `menu-navigation`.

**From the main Routes.js**

```
const Routes = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
        <Route path="/redirect" component={FirebaseRedirector} />
        <Route path="/restricted-access" component={RestrictedAccess} />
        <Route path="/change-password/:hash?" component={ChangePassword} />
        <Route path="/reset-password" exact component={ResetPassword} />
        <Route path="/" component={Main} />
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>
);

export default Routes;
```

Note once you are logged in the **Main** component above is loaded:

```
render() {
  return (
    <Main
      user={this.props.user}
      signOut={this.signOut}
    >
      <Switch>
        <Route
          path="/dashboard/categories/unmatched-api/:id?"
          component={CategoriesUnmatchedApi}
          notExact
        />
        <Route path="/dashboard/menu-navigation" exact component={MenuNavigation} />
        <Route path="/dashboard/home-screen" exact component={HomeScreen} />
        <Route path="/dashboard/categories/product-config" component={CategoryProductConfig} />
        <Route path="/dashboard/categories/:category?" component={Categories} />
        <Route path="/dashboard/playground" exact component={Playground} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" exact component={Drafts} />
        <Route path="/" exact component={Drafts} />
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </Main>
  );
}
```

---

Here is the state once you navigate to the MenuNavigation route

[image]

Then the state after refresh

[image]

Seems like react router is not respecting `<Route path="/dashboard/menu-navigation"` ?

I did notice after refresh that the **Main.js** route section gets hit 3 times, the first time the this.props.location is correct, however the next 2 times it's just `/dashboard`

[image]

Comment: Isn't it your Redux store pushing the login information after the Router initialised and attempted to match a route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! We had a redirect to the /dashboard everytime.

Inside our login actions we had:

`onAuthStateChange` -> `checkAuth` which contained this:

`dispatch(push(authDasboardView));`

After removing the dispatch to authDashboardView, this fixed the problem!